# ASP - How to get min and max date from table column

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I want to get minDate from columnOne and maxDate from columnTwo. My solution is C# Class Library for SharePoint.

**This is my code :**

```
 SPListItemCollection myItemColForTable = list.GetItems(myQueryForTable);

 List<DateTime> minDate = new List<DateTime>();
 List<DateTime> maxDate = new List<DateTime>();

  foreach (SPListItem item in myItemColForTable)
  {
     minDate.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(item["DepartureDate"].ToString()));
     maxDate.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(item["ReturnDate"].ToString()));
  }
```

**Where I'm wrong ?**

Comment: there are `Max` and `Min` methods as well. You shouldn't sort the lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use IEnumerable functions:

```
DateTime min = minDate.Min();
DateTime max = maxDate.Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `myItemColForTable.Min(p => p.DepartureDate)` and the save for `Max()`. This removes your need of your `foreach` loop.

Your code should looking something more like this:

```
SPListItemCollection myItemColForTable = list.GetItems(myQueryForTable);
var myNewList = myItemColForTable.ToList();
DateTime minDate = myNewList.Min(p => p.DepartureDate);
DateTime maxDate = myNewList.Max(p => p.ReturnDate);
```

Comment: Error 4 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Max' and no extension method 'Max' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Gohyu Whoops. Didn't really pay attention to the `SPListItemCollection` part lol. You should be able to call `.ToList()`. You may want to consider reframing your question to be more SharePoint specific rather than ASP.

Comment: with updated code :

Comment: Error 1 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Gohyu sorry I can't be of more help, I don't really have any experience with SharePoint.

Comment: No problem, best regards :)